# on angular velocity of approach

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Three point particles P, Q. R move in a circle of radius' r' with different but constant speeds. They start moving at t = 0 from their initial positions as shown in the figure. The angular velocities (in rad/sec) of P, Q and R are 5π,2π&3π respectively, in the same sense. The time interval after which they all meet is

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Taking the initial position of P as the origin and measuring positively clockwise, the position, in radians, of each particle at time $t$ relative to the origin are as follows:
$$ p=5\pi t$$
$$ q=2\pi t+\frac{\pi}{2}$$
$$ r=3\pi t +\pi$$

For P and Q to be in the same position on the circle at time $t$ we require $$p=q \mod 2\pi$$
$$\Rightarrow 5\pi t=2\pi t +\frac{\pi}{2}+n.2\pi, n\in \mathbb Z^+$$
$$\Rightarrow t=\frac 16+n.\frac 23$$

Similarly, for P and R to be in the same position, we also have $$t=\frac 12+m, m\in \mathbb Z^+$$
Solving these, we have $$3m=2n-1$$ for which we can choose $m=1$ and $n=2$, which gives $$t=1.5$$

Comment: Wait a second , so if you have a couple of things spinning with different speeds , they will  all always meet at some time before infinity because you get the answer by solving a line for lattice point which will exist if the line stretches to infinity ? Very strange imo